# TCP Client C#: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, tcpclient

I am trying to establish a communication between a C# client  and a C# server through TCP/SSL.

I have generated self signed certificate using IIS and imported it into the trust store.

The communication works well when the client and the server are **hosted on the same machine**. (I am able to exchange packets).

But when the client is on another machine, I am getting this error : the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

- I have recreated the certificate. (same error)

  ```
   public static bool ValidateCertifiate(object sender, X509Certificate   certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {

    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
     return true;
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);
    return false;
    }
  ```

// Main code

```
   public static int Main(string[] args){

   TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("IP", 8080);

  SslStream stream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false, new   RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCertifiate), null);

  try {
   stream.AuthenticateAsClient("CertificateIssuer");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
 }

 }
```

I am wondering why the program is working when the client is on the same host of the server and not working when the client is on different machine.

Comment: Did you import the self-signed certificate to the trust store of the client? Or just the server?

Comment: the client has to trust the server, so you have to import the certificate on the client.

Comment: Is it planned to always have both programs run on the same server? If yes then a named pipe (managed by Windows with security ACL settings) would have been the better alternative compared to a TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

I imported the certificate on the right client trust store. Now the communication is established.

Thanks